# Download PDF file for offline viewing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pdf-viewer

I'm trying to cache PDF files on the user's device and open them within my app at a later time.

With this package: https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

I use `pdfView.fromUri(uri)` which loads the file from the URL every time the page is loaded.
Is there a function I can use to cache these files for offline viewing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the PDF yourself, using your favorite HTTP client API. Then, use `fromFile()` rather than `fromUri()`.

Comment: But I don't want users to have access to the pdf file. I just want them to be able to view it within the app

Comment: @dbkonXepts: Download the PDF yourself, to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), using your favorite HTTP client API. Then, use `fromFile()` rather than `fromUri()`.